# Which species does or do בקר refer to in the Torah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, animals, translation

Are only cows and bulls included?
Or perhaps other related species as well?
Is this subject to disagreement?
And does context make a difference?

Comment: All the instances of which I can think refer to bovine livestock, i.e. collective domesticated *Bos*. What species did you have in mind? Something like the aurochs (*re'em*) isn't referred to as *bakar*; the Torah's list of kosher mammals include some other wild ones but they're not called *bakar.* The Talmud Brachos 33a talks about a "black ox" in ways that are most likely a water buffalo, but the word *bakar* isn't used.

Comment: Thank you! I don't really anything about animals so was just curious when learning last week's parsha. This was super helpful but when I looked up bovine it did make me more confused. Do you know of any simple (online) resources that explain and categorize the various species of animals (ideally with pictures) so I can get a better sense of what's included in בקר and the differences between the species?

Comment: IIRC, specification is subject to rabbinic tradition. As long as rabbis (different rabbis in different places) call something "a cow" it is "a cow" de jure.